# Dompdf returns PDF on Controller function but not on Submit Form function

Tags: 8, forms, files

I'm using Drupal's Form api to create a form which returns some values inside a PDF document based on some selected inputs. I'm importing the form like so:

```
public function content(){
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\custom_module_name\Form\ContributeForm');
    ...
    ... and so on
```

In my ContributeForm::submitForm I have this code:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml('<h1>hello world</h1>');
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("example.pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));
    if ($dompdf){
        drupal_set_message("DOMPDF");
    }
    foreach($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value){
        drupal_set_message($key . ': ' . $value);
    }
```

and I don't get a pdf doc on the reloading of the page, though I do get the contents selected in the form returned to me in the drupal_set_message call.

Now to sanity check, I created a dummy module with only a controller (no form import) and this one DOES return the PDF with the content inside ::loadHtml:

```
public function content(){

    $domp = new Dompdf();
    $domp->loadHtml('<h1>Hi</h1>');
    $domp->setPaper('A4');
    $domp->render();
    $domp->stream('example.pdf');

    return array(
        //'#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => $this->t('Hello World yall'),
    );

}
```

Am I missing something on the form return? Am I adding an unnecessary layer of complications by importing the form into the controller, and should I just have the form load to it's own url?

Answer (score 1):

By default after form submit drupal makes a redirect, if there is no redirect defined intentionally allways will go to current url. To prevent this, you need call to *disableRedirect()* method from FormState at the final of *submitForm()*.

Example:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml('<h1>hello world</h1>');
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("example.pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));
    if ($dompdf){
        drupal_set_message("DOMPDF");
    }
    foreach($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value){
        drupal_set_message($key . ': ' . $value);
    }
    // Prevent form redirection to print PDF.
    $form_state->disableRedirect();
}
```

Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AdisableRedirect/8.2.x

Other option, more dirty, is call to exit() method from PHP (http://php.net/manual/es/function.exit.php) also at the final of the function.